PID package with PID controllers specified in URDF
I am trying to tune the PIDs of my robot with this package:
http://wiki.ros.org/pid
by running the node "autotune".
My PIDs are specified as usual: a config.yaml file with the list of controllers i.e. effort_controllers/JointPositionInterface and then the values of the parameters.
My question is: in order to run the node, do I need to adjust the controllers in the PID package to the ones of the URDF or it's the other way around?
